# Iodine Titration with Free SO2 in wine

Tags: titration

To determine the free $\ce{SO2}$ in wine, a common method used is called the Ripper Titration Method.

The equation is as follows: $$\ce{SO2 (aq) + I2 (aq) + 2H2O (l) -> 4H+ (aq) + SO4^2- (aq) + 2I- (aq)}$$

This method involves titrating an Iodine solution into a sample of wine. I have found that triiodide is made from reacting $\ce{I-}$ with $\ce{I2}$. However, if it is the triiodide we are titrating, how is the iodine reacting with the wine?

Is it triiodide ($\ce{I3-}$) that is being titrated with the wine sample or iodine ($\ce{I2}$)?

Comment: @Nij States of aggregation should not be subscripted, it is not wrong, but the [recommendations (Sec. 2.1.)](http://pac.iupac.org/publications/pac/pdf/1982/pdf/5406x1239.pdf) are different.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン just fitting form based on how I would write for P&P. I'll check those recommendations for other details later, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Reaction goes along the lines $\ce{3 I2 -> 2 I3- -> 6 I-}$. The beginning of titration is $\ce{I2}$. The end of titration is $\ce{I-}$. $\ce{I3-}$ forms as an intermediate, but it can be ignored in titration.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: I have down voted this because while it isn't completely wrong, it contains not explanation and should have probably better be left as a comment.

Comment: @martin, Downvoting something that is not wrong (or that is honestly right) is an interesting practice. What do you disagree with?